# GitPython debug logs not available

Tags: python, git, gitpython

In case I run a simple git command like

```
git fetch origin

remote: Counting objects: 26, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 26 (delta 13), reused 12 (delta 12), pack-reused 8
Unpacking objects: 100% (26/26), done.
From https://github.com/edorado93/jocular
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
ed17d20..6e70ecd  master     -> origin/master
```

I want similar logs while executing this command using GitPython module. So the command goes something like this

```
git.fetch('origin')
```

I set the environment variable `type(repo.git).GIT_PYTHON_TRACE="full"` . Still on executing my script, I don't get any git logs on the console.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the logging, without which GitPython doesn't seem to want to log anything:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

An example after this:

```
from git.cmd import Git
g = Git()
type(g).GIT_PYTHON_TRACE="full"
g.fetch('origin')
```

which outputs:

```
INFO:git.cmd:git fetch origin -> 0
''
```